# Is there a way to get WAN mini-port statistics in windows?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

Is there code or API (either C++/C#) to get WAN mini-port statistics similar to status report when it is connected?

[image: WAN Mini-port statistics]

Comment: Were you developing an [UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide) app?

Comment: Yes this is for an UWP application..

Answer (score 1):

In UWP, you could use [NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.getinternetconnectionprofile) to get the connection profile associated with the internet connection currently used by the local machine, or you could use [NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.getconnectionprofiles) to get a list of profiles for connections, active or otherwise, on the local machine.

Then, you could use [ConnectionProfile.GetNetworkUsageAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.connectivity.connectionprofile.getnetworkusageasync#Windows_Networking_Connectivity_ConnectionProfile_GetNetworkUsageAsync_Windows_Foundation_DateTime_Windows_Foundation_DateTime_Windows_Networking_Connectivity_DataUsageGranularity_Windows_Networking_Connectivity_NetworkUsageStates_) to get a list of the estimated data traffic and connection duration over a specified period of time, for a specific network usage state.

After that, you could get the [NetworkUsage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.connectivity.networkusage)'s `BytesReceived` and `BytesSent` data.

I made a simple code sample for your reference:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var internetConnectionProfile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
    var usageStates = new NetworkUsageStates
    {
        Roaming = TriStates.DoNotCare,
        Shared = TriStates.DoNotCare
    };
    var networkUsage = await internetConnectionProfile.GetNetworkUsageAsync(
            DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-1),
            DateTimeOffset.Now,
            DataUsageGranularity.Total,
            usageStates);
    foreach (var usage in networkUsage)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(internetConnectionProfile.ProfileName+" Sent: "+usage.BytesSent+" Received: "+usage.BytesReceived);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet, I tried it out but doesn't list miniports. Is there a way to access a profile name directly and get stats?

Comment: @TomIv No. There's no such a way.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read, it looks like this is most easily accessed via performance counters.

The Network Adapter section in particular, lists out the juicy details for each network adapter.

There are many tutorials out there for reading performance counters in C#, but here's one I like: https://dotnetcodr.com/2017/03/29/reading-the-value-of-a-performance-counter-on-windows-with-c-net-3